# Выбор определенных значений во всплывающем окне

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть основное окно, есть кнопка выбора товара, после нажатия происходит открытие нового окна со списком товаров. После выбора товара нужно зафиксировать выбранное значение в основном окне.
Как реализовать перенос значений из всплывающего окна в основное?

```
<script>
function OpenWin(){
    window.open("http://my.com/", "newWin", "width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight)
}
</script>

<a href="javascript: OpenWin();">Выбор товара</a>
```

Comment: попробуйте передать через `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете получить доступ к DOM родителя из дочернего окна через window.opener
Подробнее здесь - https://javascript.ru/window.opener

Например

```
var opener = window.opener;
if(opener) {
    var parentDom = opener.document;
    var elem = parentDom.getElementById("chosen_item");
    if (elem) {
        elem.innerHtml = 'товар зафиксирован';
    }
}
```